# Qt Command Pattern QHash/QMap

Tags: java, c++, qt, qmap, qhash

I've recently implemented a command design pattern in Java with the use of:

```
private HashMap<Component, CommandInterface> commands;
```

Where `Component` is any Java Component (`JButton`, `JMenuItem`, ...) and `CommandInterface` is an interface for my Command-Classes.

So my question is: How can I accomplish this with C++/Qt ?

I've already used `QMap` and `QHash`, but both of them need an overloaded operator (`operator<` or `operator==`) for their `Key`-values.

Is the only possible way to derive from `QObject` and overload `operator<` ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

One very important difference between Java and C++ is that C++ makes a distinction between an object pointer (reference in Java) `QObject* o;` and an object value `QObject o;`

That being said, Qt strongly encourages to create the QObject on the heap (using new). So you end up with QObject pointers `QObject*`. Then your hashmap will work because comparing the pointers is like comparing integers.

```
QHash<QObject*, CommandInterface*> commands;
```

**Do not forget** to manage the lifetime of your objects though, you do not have a garbage collector like in Java. You can use the Qt tree ownership for convenience, depending on your needs : http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/objecttrees.html

Comment: Didn't know, you can use a pointer as the `Key` for `QHash` because of the `qHash()` function that needs to be provided. Thank you, I will give it a go !

Comment: @ChristianB as I said a pointer is just an integer value (the memory address) so it can be used as such, and Qt provides `qHash()` for most of common C++ types and Qt data and container classes (QString, QVector etc).